# Different sql results between "Azure Mobile Services" and "Azure App Service"

Tags: javascript, sql, json, database, azure-mobile-services

I got two different results when running the same SQL statements between Azure Mobile Service(the old service) and Azure App Service(the new service)

The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY score_tot DESC) AS row, score_tot FROM Player
```

When i run it as an old Azure Mobile Service with the ***request.service.mssql.query()*** function i got a json result looking like this:

[ { row: **1**, score_tot: 45674 },

{   row: **2**, score_tot: 21234 }]

but when i run the same SQL statement with the new Azure App Service using the
***request.azureMobile.data.execute(SQL)*** function
i got this:

[ { row: **'1'**, score_tot: 45674 },

{   row: **'2'**, score_tot: 21234 }]

the App Service returns the row columns as a string/text and not as a number as it does in mobile service.

Why is there a difference between these two results and what can i do to get the row columns as numbers in app service?
Shouldn't the app service return same results for same SQL statement as the old service?

/T

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, Azure Mobile Apps SDK for node.js uses [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) npm package as SQL Server driver. Following are my screenshot of testing, it seems that `node-mssql` lets `ROW_NUMBER()` function returns varchar value instead of int.
[image: code snippet][image: return result]

As a workaround, you could try to use the SQL below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY score_tot DESC)) AS row, score_tot FROM Player
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast answer.
I think is a little bit strange that it isn't consistent between those two services.
There can be some strange behaviours if you upgrade against this new service and expect to behave in same way.
In my case i did some calculations on the returned integer row values and when i changed to this new service 
it started doing string concatenations instead.